# Unpivot all other columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

Im new to Stack overflow and SQL and I'm trying to replicate a function in Microsoft Power Query to use in SQL instead.

I know how to Unpivot and keep 1 Column in SQL and then had to reference all the other columns by name to make the unpivot.

Now I need to Keep 3 ID columns and Unpivot the rest of the columns
(This table has 355 columns right now and will change)

Can anyone help me with this?

This is the furthest I got (Thanks to RAV DBLearning on Youtube), but I cant seem to find a way to Convert the columns types to 1 type.

```
DECLARE 
@SQLSTRING NVARCHAR(MAX),
@COLUMNLIST NVARCHAR(1000) = ''

SELECT
@COLUMNLIST = @COLUMNLIST + QUOTENAME(NAME) + ','
FROM
sys.columns
WHERE 
OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('xp.XPROPERTYVALUES') AND
--COLUMN_ID NOT IN(1,2,3)
COLUMN_ID IN(452,453,454)

SELECT 
@COLUMNLIST = LEFT(@COLUMNLIST,LEN(@COLUMNLIST)-1)

SET 
@SQLSTRING = 
'
SELECT 
upv.id,
upv.item_id,
upv.itemtype_id,
upv.X_Category,
upv.X_Values
FROM 
xp.XPROPERTYVALUES
UNPIVOT
(
X_Values FOR X_Category 
IN 
(' + @COLUMNLIST + ')
) AS upv
'

PRINT 
(@SQLSTRING)
EXECUTE 
sp_executesql @SQLSTRING
```

Answer (score 0):

It just needs a source query.
And you can re-use the calculated column list for that.

```
DECLARE @SQLSTRING NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @COLUMNLIST NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE @TABLENAME VARCHAR(30) = 'xp.XPROPERTYVALUES';

SELECT @COLUMNLIST = CONCAT(@COLUMNLIST + ', ', QUOTENAME(NAME)) 
FROM sys.columns
WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(@TABLENAME) 
  AND LOWER(NAME) NOT LIKE '%id';

SET @SQLSTRING = N'SELECT upv.id
, upv.item_id, upv.itemtype_id
, upv.X_Category, upv.X_Values
FROM 
(
 SELECT id, item_id, itemtype_id, 
 '+  @COLUMNLIST + N' 
 FROM '+ @TABLENAME +N'
) src
UNPIVOT
(
  X_Values FOR X_Category IN (' + @COLUMNLIST + N')
) upv';

-- SELECT @SQLSTRING;
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLSTRING;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2b5a30dfc876bc74891643cc3857a952)*

Comment: Without Naming the columns you want to be changed?

Comment: i tried just copying pasting the code you sent and i got the same error :(


 
    Msg 8167, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
    The type of column "XP-XP_FT_SIZE$IS_DEFINED" conflicts with the type of other 
    columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

Comment: Robert651723 Oh buggers. Different datatypes that cause troubles for the pivot... That complates things. If you wouldn't need the problematic columns then it would just be a matter of avoiding them in the query on sys.columns.  Not sure how to cast them in the unpivot.

Comment: Anyway. You need to identify the type of columns that cause trouble. Then add a simplified create statement for a table with a few columns to your question. Makes it easier for us to test if a solution would work.